# `test:first job: script should be a string or an array of a strings`

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I'd like to create a simple "hello, world" Gitlab CI script. I already got the Docker runner working and I'm experimenting with something like this:

```
image: debian:sid

test:first:
  script:
  - true
```

Unfortunately, the build fails with the error: `test:first job: script should be a string or an array of a strings`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a bit of experimenting, I found the root cause and [reported it as a bug](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlab-ci/issues/635). Apparently "true" was evaluated as a boolean here. Adding path to `true` executable helped solve the problem.

Comment: I have also seen this error when I just need to convert all my tabs to spaces, when it should have complained about indentation, but instead gave me this error.

Answer (score 0):

Double-check your spacing on the list lines - specifically that each dash is followed by a space.  It can be an easy thing to overlook, especially if the "list" is only a single item.

(Though admittedly, that was **not** the cause of error in your "Hello world" CI file)